# Proof that addition preserves order

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, proof-verification, induction

**Definition**: Let $a$ and $b$ be natural numbers. We say that $a \geq b$ (or $b \leq a$) iff we have $a = b + m$ for some natural number $m$.

**Claim**: $a \geq b$ iff $a + c \geq b + c$ for any natural number $c$.

**Proof**: We must show that $\forall c, (a \geq b \implies a + c \geq b + c)$ and that $\forall c (a + c \geq b + c \implies a \geq b)$

First we prove $a + c \geq b + c \implies a \geq b$. By definition, $a + c = b + c + m$ for some natural number $m$. By cancellation law, $a = b + m$ which means $a \geq b$.

Next we prove $a \geq b \implies a + c \geq b + c$. We induct on $c$. When $c=0$, we see that $a \geq b \implies a + 0 \geq b + 0$ which is true. During the inductive step we assume $a \geq b \implies a + c \geq b + c$ and need to show that $a \geq b \implies a + c + 1 \geq b + c + 1$. I'm not 100% sure where to go from here.

Edit: Maybe this: $a + c + 1 \geq b + c + 1$ means $a + c + 1 = b + c + 1 + m$ for some $m$. By cancellation law, $a = b + m$. Therefore $a \geq b \implies a + c \geq b + c = a \geq b$ which is true. I guess this also means we didn't need induction since I didn't even use the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: $$\small\forall m\in\Bbb N~a\geq b\iff a+c=b+c+m\iff a+c+1=b+c+1+m\iff a+c+1\geq b+c+1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a \ge b$ then $a= b+m$ for some $m$.

But since $a+1=a+1$ we thus have that $a+1= b+m+1 =b+1+m$, and so $a+1 \ge b+1$

Comment: Is this technically an inductive argument? (I also edited my post, not sure if that resolves the issue any)

Comment: @user525966 I wrote just the step of the inductive argument.  And it's true that  you don't need induction for this one.

Comment: I'm not sure how you do it without induction though, unless there's an anti-cancellation law (the cancellation law I used induction for)

Comment: @user525966 Yes, you will need induction for the cancellation law, but pnce you have that, this proof of addition preserving order does not need induction. ... not sure what you mean by 'anti-cancellation' ....

Comment: Cancellation meaning you remove the same quantity from both sides, anti-cancellation (or whatever it would be called) being that you add a quantity to both sides.

Comment: @user525966 Oh! I just explained in the comment below Alvaro's post that that is trivial!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $a\geq b$, then $a=b+m$ for some natural $m$. If $c\in\mathbb{N}$, then $a+c=b+c+m$, so $a+c\geq b+c$, because $m\in\mathbb{N}$, and the definition is met. No need for induction.

Comment: Is there a name for this? I can show the cancellation law with induction but I don't know if there's something for the reverse of this (adding a number to both sides of an equality)

Comment: @user525966 If $a=b$ then you can get $a+c=b+c$ as follows: it is a logical truth that $a+c=a+c$, and so if $a=b$ you can substitute $b$ for the second $a$ in $a+c=a+c$ to get $a+c=b+c$

Comment: @user525966 If $a=b+m$, then $a+c=(b+m)+c=b+c+m$. For these simple properties of group operations, induction is not necessary (since they don't only apply in the ring of integer numbers, and induction doesn't exist elsewhere). If your hypothesis is that two objects are equal, then those objects are interchangeable everywhere, from where follows the equality above.